# Read binary file into char* and convert into a struct?

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I've got a weird situation here. It is an assignment, as a forward, but I have a 10MB file `mmaped` into a `char* fs`. I need to loop through it and assign every 512 bytes to a `struct block`. `block` has four data members, `short inuse`, `short inodeNum`, `short numPlace`, and `char data[506]`. The data in the binary file has been written in via `structs` as well.

I am trying to read in 512 bytes from the binary file into a `char* dataBlock` (`malloced` to size 512 bytes) and then convert `char* dataBlock` into my `struct block`. I've tried typecasting, and it returns incorrect values. I've tried `memcpy` as well as bit shifting and bitwise math.

I've attempted to make another program to replicate the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  short testShort;
  int testInt;
} testStruct;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  testStruct temp;
  temp.testShort = 640;
  temp.testInt = 420;

  long fileLength;
  FILE* tempFile;

  tempFile = fopen(argv[1], "wb+");
  fseek(tempFile, 0, SEEK_END);
  fileLength = ftell(tempFile);
  rewind(tempFile);

  char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);

  fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, tempFile);

  fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 6, tempFile);
  fclose(tempFile);

  temp2 = (testStruct *)buffer;

  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  printf("%d\n", temp2->testShort);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);` --> `char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(testStruct));`,  `fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 6, tempFile);` --> `rewind(tempFile); fread(buffer, sizeof(testStruct), 1, tempFile);`

Answer (score 1):

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 6, tempFile);
```

As noted in comment, you should use `sizeof(testStruct)` instead of `6`, because the compiler may pad the structure, so the size could be `8` for example.

You don't need to create a character buffer and cast it in to `testStruct`. You can use a reference and read the data directly. Example:

```
testStruct temp2;
fread(&temp2, sizeof(testStruct), 1, tempFile);
```

Also add `rewind` before reading the file. You don't seem to need the file size in this example, so you can skip that part:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("error\n");  
        return 0;   
    }

    testStruct temp = { 640, 420 };

    FILE* tempFile;
    tempFile = fopen(argv[1], "wb+");

    fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, tempFile);

    rewind(tempFile);
    testStruct temp2;
    fread(&temp2, sizeof(testStruct), 1, tempFile);
    fclose(tempFile);

    printf("%d\n", temp2.testShort);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If for some reason you actually need to work with char *, you can always define a union with char [sizeof (testStruct)] and testStruct.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to replace the call to the `rewind()` function (which is not defined in Standard C) with `fseek(tempFile, 0L, SEEK_SET)`. This does [move the current position](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) to the beginning of the file, and is declared in `<stdio.h>` together with the file access functions you already use.

---

And by the way, you generally can't use `ftell()` to determine the size of a file, see the [discussion in the CERT C Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file) why this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: `rewind` is defined in Standard C.(**7.21.9.5 The rewind function**)

Comment: Ups - you're right! (Never used it.) And it is actually not quite equivalent to `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)`:

Comment: ... as `rewind()`

Comment: (f**k, I keep hitting the Enter key and terminate comments involuntarily ...) - anyway: `rewind()` [does clear the end-of-file and error flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind), I tried to say ...

Comment: It is true for clear error flags that there is a difference. but EOF not. I think that it will not be a reason not to use it.

Comment: Oh, that seems to be an error in the description over at _cppreference_! Indeed ISO 9899 (any edition) only specifies that the error indicator is cleared. Whether this is a reason to use one or the other - I don't know. The `rewind()` function seems a bit redundant anyway, IMO. But that's not actually a reason not to use it ;-)